# Unexpected InvalidOperationException when trying to change relationship via property default value

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, entity-framework-core-3.1

In the sample code below I get the following exception when doing `db.Entry(a).Collection(x => x.S).IsModified = true`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'B'
>   cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id:
>   0}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure
>   that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Why doesn't it add instead of attach the instances of B?

Strangely the documentation for `IsModified` doesn't specify `InvalidOperationException` as a possible exception. Invalid documentation or a bug?

I know this code is strange, but I wrote it only to understand how ef core works in some weird egde cases. What I want is an explanation, not a work around.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<B> S { get; set; } = new List<B>() { new B {}, new B {} };
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext {
        private const string connectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Apa;Trusted_Connection=True";

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder o)
        {
            o.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            o.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder m)
        {
            m.Entity<A>();
            m.Entity<B>();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new Db()) {
            db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            db.Add(new A { });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = new Db()) {
            var a = db.Set<A>().Single();
            db.Entry(a).Collection(x => x.S).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are A and B are related? meaning what is the relationship property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The reason of the error in the provided code is follows.**

When you get created entity `A` from the database its property `S` is initialized with a collection that contains two new records `B`. `Id` of each of this new `B` entities is equal to `0`.

```
// This line of code reads entity from the database
// and creates new instance of object A from it.
var a = db.Set<A>().Single();

// When new entity A is created its field S initialized
// by a collection that contains two new instances of entity B.
// Property Id of each of these two B entities is equal to 0.
public ICollection<B> S { get; set; } = new List<B>() { new B {}, new B {} };
```

After executing line of code `var a = db.Set<A>().Single()` collection `S` of entity `A` does not contain `B` entities from the database, because `DbContext Db` does not use lazy loading and there is no explicit loading of the collection `S`. Entity `A` only contains new `B` entities that were created during initialization of collection `S`.

When you call `IsModifed = true` for collection `S` entity framework tries to add those two new entites `B` into change tracking. But it fails because both new `B` entities have the same `Id = 0`:

```
// This line tries to add to change tracking two new B entities with the same Id = 0.
// As a result it fails.
db.Entry(a).Collection(x => x.S).IsModified = true;
```

You can see from the stack trace that entity framework tries to add `B` entities into the `IdentityMap`:

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetPropertyModified(IProperty property, Boolean changeState, Boolean isModified, Boolean isConceptualNull, Boolean acceptChanges)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry.SetFkPropertiesModified(InternalEntityEntry internalEntityEntry, Boolean modified)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry.SetFkPropertiesModified(Object relatedEntity, Boolean modified)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry.set_IsModified(Boolean value)
```

And the error message also tells that it cannot track `B` entity with `Id = 0` because another `B` entity with the same `Id` is already tracked.

---

**How to resolve this problem.**

To resolve this problem you should delete code that creates `B` entities when initializing `S` collection:

```
public ICollection<B> S { get; set; } = new List<B>();
```

Instead you should fill `S` collection at the place where `A` is created. For example:

```
db.Add(new A {S = {new B(), new B()}});
```

If you don't use lazy loading you should explicitly load `S` collection to add its items into change tracking:

```
// Use eager loading, for example.
A a = db.Set<A>().Include(x => x.S).Single();
db.Entry(a).Collection(x => x.S).IsModified = true;
```

---

> **Why doesn't it add instead of attach the instances of B?**

**In short**, they are attached insted of being added because they have `Detached` state.

After executing line of code

```
var a = db.Set<A>().Single();
```

created instances of entity `B` have state `Detached`. It can be verified using the next code:

```
Console.WriteLine(db.Entry(a.S[0]).State);
Console.WriteLine(db.Entry(a.S[1]).State);
```

Then when you set

```
db.Entry(a).Collection(x => x.S).IsModified = true;
```

EF tries to add `B` entities to change tracking. From source code of [EFCore](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore) you can see that this leads us to the method [InternalEntityEntry.SetPropertyModified](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/InternalEntityEntry.cs#L429) with the next argument values:

- `property` - one of our `B` entities,
- `changeState = true`,
- `isModified = true`,
- `isConceptualNull = false`,
- `acceptChanges = true`.

This method with such arguments changes state of the `Detached` `B` entites to `Modified`, and then tries to start tracking for them (see lines [490](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/InternalEntityEntry.cs#L490) - 506). Because `B` entities now have state `Modified` this leads them to be attached (not added).

Comment: Where is the answer for "Why doesn't it add instead of attaching the instances of B?" You are saying "it fails because both new B entities have the same Id = 0". I think it is wrong because ef core saves both with 1 and 2 ids. I don't think it is correct answer for this question

Comment: @DIlshod K Thanks for the comment. In the "How to resolve this problem" section I wrote that collection `S` should be loaded explicitly, because provided code don't use lazy loading. Of course, EF saved previously created `B` entities in the database. But the line of code `A a = db.Set<A>().Single()` only loads entity `A` without entities in the collection `S`. To load collection `S` eager loading should be used. I'll change my asnwer to explicitly include answer to the question "Why doesn't it add instead of attaching the instances of B?".